# Accessing Hidden field or variable from the aspx page to its child user control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hidden-field, local-variables

I have an master aspx page and two user controls. In user control 1, I had an Hidden field(i.e Hiddenfield1) and i'm looking to use that hidden field value in user Control2. So far this is what i have done,

1) register usercontrol 1 in usercontrol 2 and created another hidden field in user control 2 and by using set and get, i tried to assign usercontrol1 value to hidden field in usercontrol 2, but in not worked

code snippets:

In user control 2:

```
 Me.VarUC2 = Me.Usercontrol1ID.VarUC1
```

But in this one, it is returning null and VarUC1 is assigned to another local integer variable in master page. Is it possible to get VarUC2 value from variable in master page. Please let me know how to resolve this one.

Comment: CType(Me.Parent.FindControl("IdOfUC1"), TypeOfUC1).VarUC1 - NOTE: You may need to go up a few levels to find your control and this makes your code more brittle to the markup unless you make some sort of recursive function.

Comment: It is not working.. Can you please let me how to get integer variable value from aspx page to it's user control? I assigned VarUC1 to a variable in master page(i.e @varMaster), Can i get VarMaster in usercontrol 2?? @NoAlias

Comment: Add a HiddenField and assign the value to that.  Then you do the same CType deal but to a HiddenField.  Step through and use a break point and the Watch window so you can identify how many .Parent.Parent.Parent.etc you have to do to get to the Master Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a hidden field on the Master Page, you must first gain an instance of the Master Page from your User Control.  Typically the Master Page is the first Control on the Page Property that is accessible from any Control in ASP.Net.  Once you have the instance of the Master Page you can then use the FindControl method and Cast the result as a Hidden Field.  Although this can be done on one line, I've broken the example out to multiple lines to make it easier to follow.  Just replace "IdOfYourHiddenField" with the actual ID.

```
    Dim objTargetPage As Page = CType(sender, Control).Page

    Dim objMasterPage As Control = CType(objTargetPage.Controls(0), Control)

    Dim hdnTarget As HiddenField = CType(objMasterPage.FindControl("IdOfYourHiddenField"), HiddenField)

    Dim intValue As Integer = CInt(hdnTarget.Value)
```

Comment: I tried like this:: 
** UIHiddenFieldUC2 = CType(Me.Page.Master.FindControl("[UIHiddenFieldMasterPage]"), HiddenField) **


** Me.IntUC2 = CInt(UIHiddenFieldUC2.Value) **

..............But it is throwing "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. It seems master page hidden field value is erasing by the time execution reaches this point.
  Can you please suggest me any other ways?

Comment: You're probably getting that because UIHiddenFieldUC2 is null.  If the hidden field's value is null it would return as an empty string and you'd get an invalid cast exception with the CInt().  What you need to do is put a breakpoint on the FindControl() line and use your Watch Window to find exactly where that hidden field is in the control stack so you get a reference to it.

Comment: I added this one to watch window:: CType(Me.Page.Master.FindControl("[UIHiddenFieldExamInteger]"), HiddenField).. It is showing this in value column "Referenced object has a value of 'Nothing'. "

Comment: Yes, so now keep experimenting with values there.  Examples: Me.Page.Controls(0), Me.Page.Controls(1).FindControl("Id"), etc.  Find where your HiddenField is.